# Cookie and Request Header Mismatch In Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, token, mismatch, csrf-token

I am sending request to my server with "XSRF-TOKEN" in header fetched from cookies of my browser

```
function sendRequest() {
  let xsrfToken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
  let decodedToken = decodeURIComponent(xsrfToken);
  
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      // All my request is receiving XSRF-TOKEN in response header as 'Set-Cookie',which changes my xsrftoken
      let responseData = xhr.response;
      let responseObj = CryptojsDecrypt(responseData);
      if (responseObj.success) {
        console.log(`response received`);
      } else {
        console.log(`bad response`);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("POST", "MY_API", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', acceptValues.value);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Auth', authorizationValues.value);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentTypeValue.value);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-requested-With', XrequestedwithValues.value);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('CSRF-TOKEN', XcsrftokenValues.value);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", decodedToken);
  
  let reqData = JSON.stringify(CryptojsEncrypt({data : 'Some data here'}));
  xhr.send(reqData);
}
function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let ca = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == " ") {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Problem is every request receives "XSRF-TOKEN" from server as response header in a request as "Set-Cookie",
whenever my site is sending 3-4 request per second to server, Cookies which are going with my request and XSRF-TOKEN which was fetched from cookies are different and they should be same,
I want to make sure whenever I send request and get XSRF-TOKEN from cookies it should match with Cookies also